# Prove that $H^2(G,{\bf C}^\times ) = {\bf Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-cohomology

I want to prove this : $$H^2(G,{\bf C}^\times ) = {\bf Z}_2 $$ where
$$ G:={\rm Gal}\ ({\bf C}/{\bf R})={\bf Z}_2=\langle\alpha\rangle$$

Step 1 : normalized $2$-cocycle condition is $$ f(g,h)+
f(gh,k)=g\cdot f(h,k)+ f(g,hk)$$

So $$ f(\alpha,1)=f(1,\alpha)=0$$

Hence $$ f(\alpha,\alpha )=\alpha f( \alpha ,\alpha)
$$

So $f(\alpha,\alpha)\in {\bf R}$.

Step 2 : Consider a $1$-coboundary :

$$ F(g,h):=gf_1(h)-f_1(gh) + f_1(g) $$

$$F(1,\alpha)= f_1(1):=0,\
  F(\alpha,1)=\alpha f_1(1) =0
$$ $$
  F(\alpha,\alpha)=\alpha f_1(\alpha ) +f_1(\alpha)
$$

So let $$ f_1(\alpha ):=\frac{1}{2}f(\alpha,\alpha ) + yi $$ for any
$y$. Hence $f=F$.

So we have $H^2(G,{\bf C}^\times )=0$. Am I right ?

Comment: What type of cohomology theory are you talking about?

Comment: I do not understand "what type" You mean $H^2(G,K^\times)$ where $G$ is "Galois". Here $K^\times$ is a multiplicative group and
 $f$ has values in it Hence in above addition must be replaced by multiplication.

Comment: I was wondering if this is standard "group cohomology" or something else. I've heard of "Galois cohomology" but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I see I fix tags. And my question is about group cohomology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : Step 1 : Let $G=\langle\tau \rangle$. Let $f$ be a normalized
$2$-cocycle :
$$ f(1,\tau)=f(\tau,1)=1$$

And $$ f(\tau,\tau)f(\tau,\tau x)=\tau f(\tau ,x)f(\tau, \tau x)
$$

If $x=\tau$ then we have $$ \tau
f(\tau,\tau)=f(\tau,\tau)\Rightarrow f(\tau,\tau)\in {\bf R}
$$

Step 2 : Consider coboundary $F$ : $$ F(\tau,1)=\tau
f_1(1)f(\tau)^{-1} f(\tau )=1 \Rightarrow f_1(1):=1$$

$$ F(1,\tau)=f_1(\tau )f_1(\tau)^{-1} f_1(1)=1$$

That is $F$ is normalized.

And $$ F(\tau,\tau)=\tau f_1(\tau) f_1(\tau )=a^2+b^2 \geq 0\
(f_1(\tau):=a+b_i) $$

Comment: Are you answering your own question with a hint? I don't get it.

Comment: My hint do not contain enough explanation. Reference is 834 p. in
Floote and Dummit's book. Core of my hint is that all cocyle cannot
be from coboundary. As you know, in above calculation $F(\tau,\tau)$
is nonnegative, but we have a cocycle $f$ with $f(\tau,\tau)=-1$.